# Difference between .Resolve and .Get in Ninject

Tags: ninject

Just wanted to get some clarrification over the difference between Kernel.Resolve and Kernel.Get in ninject.

Description for Kernel.Get states

> gets an instance of the specified service by using the first binding that matches the specified constraints

Description for Kernel.Resolve states

> Resolves instances for the specified request.  The instances are not actually resolved until a consumer iterates over the enumeration.

In which situations might you use either of these?  (Right now I'm using Get exclusively)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Kernel.Get` is an extension method (or a set of extension methods to be more precise) which live in [`ResolutionExtensions.cs`](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/blob/3.2.3/src/Ninject/Syntax/ResolutionExtensions.cs).

`Kernel.Resolve` is a method of [`IResolutionRoot.cs`](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/blob/3.2.3/src/Ninject/Syntax/IResolutionRoot.cs#L48) which is implemented by `IKernel`.

Only by reading the description of the methods we can recon two things:

1. [`ResolutionExtensions.Get<T>(this IResolutionRoot root)`](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/blob/3.2.3/src/Ninject/Syntax/ResolutionExtensions.cs#L35) only returns the first match, which is resolved when the method is executed.
2. [`IResolutionRoot.Resolve(IRequest request)`](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/blob/3.2.3/src/Ninject/Syntax/IResolutionRoot.cs#L48) returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, this enumerable will resolve each match only when enumerated, and there can be more than one match.

---

Upon closer inspection,  [`ResolutionExtensions.Get<T>(this IResolutionRoot root)`](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/blob/3.2.3/src/Ninject/Syntax/ResolutionExtensions.cs#L35)'s implementation is:

```
public static T Get<T>(this IResolutionRoot root, params IParameter[] parameters)
{
    return GetResolutionIterator(root, typeof(T), null, parameters, false, true).Cast<T>().Single();
}
```

And [`GetResolutionIterator`](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/blob/3.2.3/src/Ninject/Syntax/ResolutionExtensions.cs#L380)'s implementation is

```
private static IEnumerable<object> GetResolutionIterator(IResolutionRoot root, Type service, Func<IBindingMetadata, bool> constraint, IEnumerable<IParameter> parameters, bool isOptional, bool isUnique)
{
    Ensure.ArgumentNotNull(root, "root");
    Ensure.ArgumentNotNull(service, "service");
    Ensure.ArgumentNotNull(parameters, "parameters");

    IRequest request = root.CreateRequest(service, constraint, parameters, isOptional, isUnique);
    return root.Resolve(request);
}
```

Which is essentially a wrapper method to `IResolutionRoot.Resolve`

So `ResolutionExtensions.Get<T>(this IResolutionRoot root)` is enumerating `IResolutionRoot.Resolve` using [`Enumerable.Single`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325(v=vs.110).aspx).

### Conclusion

`Kernel.Get()` == `Kernel.Resolve().Single()`

Comment: I'm glad I could help